# memory leak passing Byte() array to unmanaged COM DLL

Tags: vb.net, com-interop, unmanaged

I am passing lots of 16MB bitmaps converted to Byte() arrays via COM to a graphics engine. The engine takes a ByRef System.Array as argument.

Using CLR Profiler, I can see that the Byte() array never gets GCd, which makes sense since the GC can't know when the unmanaged DLL is done with the array (which is immediately after the call).

This is how I create the array:

```
Public Function GetByteArray(ByVal BMP_ToByteArray As Bitmaps) As Byte()
    Load(BMP_ToByteArray)
    Dim Stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    _Bitmaps(BMP_ToByteArray).Save(Stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    Stream.Close()
    GetByteArray = Stream.ToArray
    Unload(BMP_ToByteArray)
    Stream.Dispose()
End Function
```

Then I just call the DLL like this:

```
byteArray = myBitmaps.GetByteArray(theBitmaps.Bitmaps.LevelUITarget)
Textures.TX_Score = Engine.DBTexture.LoadFromFileInMemory(byteArray, 2048, 2048)
byteArray = Nothing
```

byteArray never gets freed, and at some point I run out of memory. I've tried looking at code examples for how to solve this, but most deal with objects that just want a pointer to the byte array, while I do need to pass a system.array, not a pointer.

This is all in VB.NET 2010, the unmanaged DLL is a VB6 DLL.

Thanks in advance for any info.
Daniel

Comment: Getting rid of these huge byte arrays requires a gen#2 collection.  Use Perfmon.exe to look at the GC counters for your program, some odds that you don't get enough collections to keep you out of trouble.  Particularly an issue with the Bitmap class, there is no evidence that you call its Dispose() method.  Disposing is easy to ignore, except for that class.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your answer. I do .dispose the bitmap itself, that's handled in the Unload() function in GetByteArray(). I also manually GC.Collect() periodically after large changes of game scenes, which works out to be after 2 of these byte arrays were created. Are you sure a Gen 2 GC will dispose of byte arrays even if I passed them ByRef to unmanaged code?

Comment: I just checked with CLR Profiler: Within just a few minutes I had 77 Gen2 collections, but none of the arrays got freed, so that cannot be it.